# Is it possible to multi file upload usign codeigniter 1.7 and a loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I've been trying to do a multi file upload with codeigniter 1.7. I'm having issues to say the least!

I know its an old version but that's what I've got to work with.

Can I loop the $_FILES array and upload each one? It doesn't seem to work.

Heres what I've got?

```
        $dir_name = $this->input->post('dir');

    $file_path = "./system/application/views/courses/course/";

    $full_file_path = $file_path . $dir_name;


    if (!file_exists($full_file_path)) {
        mkdir($full_file_path, 0777, true);
    }

    $config['upload_path'] = $full_file_path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'php|js|html';

    $this->load->library('upload');

    foreach ($_FILES as $files => $fileObject)  //
    {
        if (!empty($fileObject['name']))
        {
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($files))
            {
                $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "It worked";
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this possible?

This code runs but doesn't upload the files?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope This will help

```
$name_array=array(); 
$count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
foreach($_FILES as $key => $value)
{
    for ($s = 0; $s < $count; $s++)
    {
$_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $value['name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $value['type'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $value['error'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $value['size'][$s];
        $config['upload_path'] = "uploads/item_images/itemimage/original/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '8000';
        $config['max_width'] = '10240';
        $config['max_height'] = '7680';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload("image"))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
          if ($this->image_moo->errors)
            {
                print $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            else
            {
                $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];

            } } } }
```

Comment: You sir/miss are a legend! Been working on this for days!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can loop through $_FILES... although you probably shouldn't name an array an "object", it's a little confusing.

Here's a user manual I found, specifically for the uploads in 1.7, it appears to be substantially similar to 3.0.3. http://www.standoffsystems.com/ci/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

First, make sure your destination folder is set to 777

your `config` is outside the `foreach()` and the `$this->upload->initialize($config);` is inside, you don't need to initialize it each time since the `$config` items are, essentially, static. This isn't likely to fix your issue though.

Try this instead:

```
$config['upload_path'] = $full_file_path;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'php|js|html';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

foreach (){
   $this->upload->initialize($config); <-- remove this
   ...
}
```

I see you're not echoing out any errors, what happens if you do?

```
 echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```