# CodeIgniter Multiple Files Upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've write the codeigniter for multiple upload. But, it is always give me this error message : "You did not select a file to upload."

This is the codes that have a problem :

```
    $num = count($_FILES['product_image']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
    { 
    if (!empty($_FILES['product_image']['name'][$i])) 
    {
    $_FILES['product_image']['name']= $_FILES['product_image']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['product_image']['type']= $_FILES['product_image']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']= $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['product_image']['error']= $_FILES['product_image']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['product_image']['size']= $_FILES['product_image']['size'][$i];     

    $this->upload->do_upload('product_image');

    $this->data['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }          
    }
```

Comment: I do not see any file upload configuration http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#initializing-the-upload-class

Comment: Codeigniter 2.* does not support multiupload. The function $this->upload->do_upload(); will not work for multiupload.
Im not sure if Codeigniter 3 supports it though

Comment: @wolfgang1983
there is no problem with the upload configuration. it was tested with upload single file

Comment: @JeroenvanVeghel
I am using codeigniter 3

Comment: [here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746412/is-it-possible-to-multi-file-upload-usign-codeigniter-1-7-and-a-loop/34759507#34759507)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to run Multiupload in CI:
https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload