# Multiple images and data uploading using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

i'm beginner in codeigniter i want to upload multiple images and data upload and save images name in database. i don't understand how to store multiple files name in database. And upload images in my root folder.

Here is my code

```
****View****

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=base_url();?>vendors/home/do_upload">

                    <input type="text" name="product_name" required>

                    <input type="text" name="product_price" required>

                    <input type="text" name="old_price" required>

                    <input type="file" name="image1" required>

                    <input type="file" name="image2" required>

                    <input type="file" name="image3" required>

                    <input type="file" name="image4" required>

      </form>

********Controller:********

public function do_upload()
{

if ($_POST) {

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['max_size'] = 90000;
$config['max_width'] = 50000;
$config['max_height'] = 50000;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg';

$this->load->library('upload',$config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view('vendors/add_product',$error);

}


else{

$query = $this->upload->data();

$data = array(
          'pro_name' => $_POST['product_name'],
           'prod_price' => $_POST['product_price'], 
           'old_price' => $_POST['old_price'],  
            'prod_image1' => [' '],
            'prod_image2' => [' '],
            'prod_image3' => [' '],
            'prod_image4' => [' '],

);

$this->venmod->add_product($data);
redirect(base_url().'vendors/');
}
$this->load->view('footer');
}
}


******Model:******

public function add_product($data)

{
      $this->db->insert('vendor_products',$data);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746412/is-it-possible-to-multi-file-upload-usign-codeigniter-1-7-and-a-loop/34759507#34759507

Comment: check the  link given by @santosh . YOur question is duplicate.

Comment: i'm beginner i can't understand can you please edit my code and complete my action ?